# PHP WEB_URL/1 id number

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I would like to know how does this query works.

Like this one:

```
website_name/1
website_name/2
```

I know only one way to do this:

```
website_name/file.php?id=0
```

How do modern websites creates and executes this kind of query?

Comment: The common way of defining URL endpoints and handle dynamic URL values is to use a [router](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/122198) (<- that's a good explanation of what a router is and does). There are many good route-libraries out there.

Comment: i know now how to do it now :) thanks to you